# Could someone explain why my footer is in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my sidebar stretch to the bottom of the page. I've succeeded in making it stretch but now my footer it getting in the way. For some reason I don't know, my footer is appearing before the content div has ended, and cutting off the sidebar, as well as making the page messy.
[image]

As you can see, as soon as the footer appears, the sidebar (grey box) stops and the content is overlapped.

Could anyone point out the code that is doing this and a fix?

Comment: Is the site supposed to be aligned to the right? It looks a bit odd to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `min-height:100%;` results in a minium height of 100%, adding an additional `height:100%;` is obsolte. The browser calculates the height of elements relative to the closest block-level parent element. At the top level, the height will be relative to the browser window height.

Remove the `height: 100%` declarations where you have also specified a `min-height:100%;`, and your problem will be solved: #globalDiv, #topcontentWrapper.

Comment: But now my sidebar does not stretch down the width of the page?

Answer (score 1):

remove the height from this piece of css:

```
 #topContentWrapper {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

change to

```
#topContentWrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```